# Causing an image not to be added to the dom tree on an img's onerror handler

Tags: ajax, dhtml

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I'm loading an image that may or may not exist on the server.
The image onerror handler is triggered when the image does not exist.
What I want to do is to remove the image from the dom tree (not to make the broken image icon appear).

the following:

```
onerror="this.parentElement.removeChild(this);"
```

Works on Chrome but not on firefox. The reason for it is that the image is not yet attached to the domtree (parentElement is null).

I have also tried setting the src attribute to some transparent image on the server but then my onload evenhandler gets called eventhough I've set:

```
onerror="this.onload=null;this.src='transparentimage';"
```

Is there another way of achieving what I want?

Can't figure it out!

Any briliant ideas?

Best regards,

Niclas

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this problem:

```
<img src="imageURL" style="display:none" onload="this.style.display='block'"/>
```

Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: I have no idea if this applies to the plain vanilla JavaScript load event, but the jQuery documentation says that its .load() is not reliable (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).  So it might be better to use onerror instead.  style to "display: block" and onerror set display to none.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with jQuery:
$("img").error(function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });

Note that for IE, you should set the error handler after the items in the HTML.  If you do it on document.ready() it won't trigger.